# HTTP status of my request

Tags: http, status

I have one question. When I want return the status http of my request when in database we haven't data, for it's this status.

Comment: You can use a protocol analyzer to inspect/monitor network packets, Wireshark is a useful program.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP status code for "no data available" from an external datasource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595151/http-status-code-for-no-data-available-from-an-external-datasource)